# SecPKCS12Import function doesn't work properly if run agent/daemon under root

Tags: objective-c, macos, keychain, launchd, security-framework

I have OSX agent which should read data from p12 file which placed in the project. There is a function SecPKCS12Import from Security.framework which do that. The problem is that if I run agent under root right after installing into appropriated folder the following function doesn't return certificate's data (&items parameter) but returns status error "0".

```
sudo launchctl load com.myagent.agent.plist
```

But after OSX reboot agent startups under root and works fine.

If run agent under user permissions it works fine even without OSX reboot.

Here is a plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/myagent/agent.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/myagent/agent.log</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myagent.agent</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/agent.app/Contents/MacOS/agent</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I use OSX 10.8

How to solve the problem above?